# Firestore arrays

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with loading arrays from firebase firestore.

my code:

```
 const [trackscreenData, setTrackscreenData] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        // Alleen preview
           function getTracksData() {
                let TrackData = firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('TrackScreen')
                    .doc('LeerjarenData')
                    .get();
                if (!TrackData.exists) {
                    console.log('No Data')
                } else {
                    let TrackDatav2 = TrackData.data();
                    setTrackscreenData(TrackDatav2) 
                }
           } getTracksData()
    }, [])

    console.log(trackscreenData.ModulePbs1);
```

This works perfect, it loads the data but when I change the console to

```
console.log(trackscreenData.ModulePbs1[0]);
```

and save the console still gives me the data I want but when I reload it gives me the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

so when I just load the whole array its no problem but when I want a specific query from the array, on the first render it gives me this error, because the data isn't loaded I guess but how do I fix this?

Comment: `useState({ModulePbs1: []})` should resolve it. It'll still log `undefined` as it's an empty array but won't throw an error..

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So it was a problem which i had not with the code but with something else with Firebase, now it is fine but the answer here are good answers but not the answer i was looking for

Comment: In that case please consider posting your own answer of how you solved the problem. Without that, this page is gonna be pretty useless for anyone who lands here in the future. Keep in mind: on Stack Overflow we're not (just) helping you solve a problem, we're also all building a knowledge base for developers going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the default value for the state as an array, not a string:

```
const [trackscreenData, setTrackscreenData] = useState([])
```

Without that, the first time the `console.log(trackscreenData.ModulePbs1[0])` runs it turns into `''[0]` which is not a valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

`getTracksData()` will be still fetching data. You need to do the following:

```js
   const [trackscreenData, setTrackscreenData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
               firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('TrackScreen')
                    .doc('LeerjarenData')
                    .get().then(docs=>{
                        setTrackscreenData(docs.docs.map(doc=> ({id: doc.id, 
                       ...doc.data()}))
}
)
    }, [])

    console.log(trackscreenData);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i think you mis understood the problem but not sure. i am nog loading multiple documents in react from firestore which i want to store in an array. i have an array in firestore which i want to load in react.

Comment: Im not getting you either now because firebase firestore stores docs in arrays of object. So what im doing right there im maping through all the docs(array) and set those docs to the state. Have you tried the code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [trackscreenData, setTrackscreenData] = useState('');
```

With this the initial value of `trackscreenData` is a an empty string but you are expecting it to be an object with a property `ModulePbs1` (an array). So your initial state should be:

```js
const [trackscreenData, setTrackscreenData] = useState({ModulePbs1: []});
```

Now `trackscreenData` has a property `ModulePbs1` however it's an empty array so `console.log(trackscreenData.ModulePbs1[0])` will log `undefined`. You can use an if statement to check if that's empty by:

```
if (!trackscreenData.ModulePbs1.length) { 
  console.log("array empty") 
} else {
  console.log(trackscreenData.ModulePbs1)
}
```